# Let $n\in\Bbb N$, $|G|=2n$, and $H$ be a subgroup of order $n$. Prove $gH=Hg$ for all $g\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am presented with the following problem:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $G$ be a group of order $2n$, and let $H$ be a subgroup of order $n$. Prove that $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$.

My initial idea was to prove that $G$ is abelian, since if $G$ is abelian, then $H$ is abelian too ($H$ is a subgroup of $G$), which means that $gH = Hg$. However, I am having difficulty proving that $G$ is abelian just from the fact that its order is $2n$. If anybody could give me any hints in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well it clearly does not work: $S_3$ is not abelian and has a subgroup of half order.

Comment: $G$ might not be abelian. You can look at my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266238/let-h-le-g-show-if-gh-g-h-2-then-h-unlhd-g-but-if-gh-3-the/4266244#4266244

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.